# Unable to install pyaudio on Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: python, linux, pyaudio, python-venv, ubuntu-21.04

Within a python `venv` via terminal I have tried to install pyaudio using `pip install pyaudio`. I continue to get the following error:

```
Collecting pyaudio
Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/user/Documents/Dev/jarvis/venv/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-n_fu8__5/pyaudio_a1072b1cc7344f699b51f2cf840e0e1f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-n_fu8__5/pyaudio_a1072b1cc7344f699b51f2cf840e0e1f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-mnx7j3d4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/Documents/Dev/jarvis/venv/include/site/python3.9/pyaudio
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-n_fu8__5/pyaudio_a1072b1cc7344f699b51f2cf840e0e1f/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-1n6GrT/python3.9-3.9.5=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/python3.9-1n6GrT/python3.9-3.9.5=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/user/Documents/Dev/jarvis/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:28:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
       28 | #include "Python.h"
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/user/Documents/Dev/jarvis/venv/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-n_fu8__5/pyaudio_a1072b1cc7344f699b51f2cf840e0e1f/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-n_fu8__5/pyaudio_a1072b1cc7344f699b51f2cf840e0e1f/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-mnx7j3d4/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/user/Documents/Dev/jarvis/venv/include/site/python3.9/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  `pip install wheel` in your terminal and try installing pyaudio again